# How to replace output properly?

Tags: replace, dice

I recently built a dice game. I asked for help on how to build a functioning button, and was able to make it. Now I'm trying to make it so that each result replaces the previous output, so I can roll the dice over and over, but only have one dice roll on the page at a time (so not a list of rolls).

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong with my below code, as I have looked up .replace and it seems to me that it should work.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My own personal Dice Roll</title>
    <script src="dice.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <button onclick="diceRoll();" id="roll">Throw Dice</button>
        <h2>Dice Game:</h2>
        <div id= "output"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

JS

```
function diceRoll() {
    const value = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * value.length + 1);
    let roll = `You rolled: ${random}`;
    output(roll);
}

function output(message) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += roll.replace(message + '<br/><br/>');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += roll.replace(message + '<br/><br/>');
```

to

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = message;
```

You can't reference `roll` from within the `output` function. It doesn't exist there. It existed in the `diceRoll` function, and you passed its value to the `output` function as `message`, so you refer to that value as `message` in the `output` function.

`x += y` is shorthand for `x = x + y`, meaning you're adding `y` to `x`. If you want to overwrite the value instead, you just use `=`.

The [replace method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) is different. To use the replace method, you need three things. You need a string that you're interested in. Then you need another string you want to search for within that first string. Then, if you found that second string within the first string, you need a third string to replace it with. It works like this:

```js
var interestingString = "i hate js";
var searchString = "hate";
var replaceString = "love";

console.log( interestingString.replace(searchString, replaceString) );
```

You could use this method to accomplish what you're trying to do, but it would be way over the top. It'd be like this:

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML.replace(document.getElementById('output').innerHTML, message);
```